# Python class has method "set", how to reference builtin set type?

Tags: python

If you have a method called "set" in a class and want to create a standard builtin "set" object somewhere else in the class, Python seems to reference the method when I do that. How can you be more specific to let Python know you mean the builtin "set", not the method "set"? More specifically, set() is being created in an _____exit_____ function.

Comment: What you ask does not make sense, a method can't shadow a builtin (except where you don't put code: the class scope) so what problem *do you see*? What happens?

Comment: +1 Here's some rep, but it's considered polite to thank the people who help you by clicking the check beside the answer that helps you the most.

Comment: Some sample code would be helpful.

Comment: the same problem exists for types:
`class A:`

`def set(self) -> None: pass`

`def ret(self) -> set[str]: return set()`
will raise an exception (TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable). using `__builtins__.set` seems to work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I know what's going on here.  Are you doing something like this?

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def set(self):
...             pass
...     def test(self, x=set):
...             return x
... 
>>> set
<type 'set'>
>>> A().test()
<function set at 0x64270>
```

This is a subtle problem due to the way methods are defined in classes.  It is what allows you to make method aliases so easily, e.g.,

```
class A(object):
    def some_method(self):
        pass
    some_other_method = some_method
```

You can either put `set` at the bottom of your class definition, or you can refer to the builtin set using `__builtins__.set`.

Comment: Another option is `def test(self, x=None):`, `if x is None: x = set`.

Answer (score 3):

Object attributes are *always* accessed via a reference, so there is no way for an object attribute to shadow a builtin.

Answer (score 2):

Usually method names are disambiguated from global names because you have to prefix `self.`.

So `self.set()` invokes your class method and `set()` invokes the global `set`.

If this doesn't help, perhaps post the code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to built-in `set` as `__builtins__.set`.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the code below you will notice that the `set` method of the `UsesSet` class does not obscure the built-in set type.

```
class UsesSet(object):
    def set(self):
        pass
    def other(self):
        my_set = set([1, 2])
        print type(my_set), my_set

obj = UsesSet()
obj.other()
```

The code above outputs **`<type 'set'> set([1, 2])`** showing that the `set()` method of our class has not hidden the built-in `set()`

If however you have module in which you have defined a function named set like below something different happens:

```
def set(arg):
    print "This is my own set function"

class UsesSet(object):
    def other(self):
        my_set = set([1, 2])
        print type(my_set), my_set

obj = UsesSet()
obj.other()
```

The code above outputs:

```
This is my own set function
<type 'NoneType'> None
```

So as you can see **a module level function with the same name as a built-in hides the built-in.**